# How to calculate the altitude of a star given the hour angle, declination, and latitude?

Tags: celestial-mechanics

I'm trying to find the altitude of a star for observing, but all I have is the hour angle and declination of the star, along with latitude of the location I'm observing from. How can I find the altitude?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this fundamental formula in spherical astronomy<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_coordinate_systems#Equatorial_%E2%86%94_horizontal)</sup>
$$\sin a=\sin \phi \sin \delta + \cos \phi \cos \delta \cos H$$
where

- $a$ is the wanted altitude,
- $\phi$ is your latitude,
- $\delta$ is the declination of the star, and
- $H$ is the hour angle, measured in the clockwise direction.

Pay attention to the units! (Don't mix degrees, radians and grads. Common cause of error!)

Since I don't know how you are familiar with the trigonometric functions (I believe pretty well), you only get $\sin a$ using that formula. You need to get the $\arcsin$ of that value in order to get wanted altitude $a$.

---

The solution above is perfectly correct in theory (on competitions, exams, and for personal use), but if you are writing a program on computer, you might find the following useful:

The factor we haven't yet addressed is the atmospheric refraction<sup>[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_refraction)</sup> It causes the star to look higher than in reality. The effect is pretty small, on range of few arc minutes.

First you need to calculate the factor $R$ by the formula<sup>[[3]](http://star-www.st-and.ac.uk/%7Efv/webnotes/chapt11.htm)</sup>
$$R=\frac{16.27''\cdot P}{273 + T}$$
where $P$ is the pressure **in millibars** and $T$ is the temperature **in degrees of Celsius**. You are perfectly fine using just $R=60''=1'$. Then the apparent altitude of the star is given by $a'=R+a$. Again, pay attention to the units (everything in degrees or everything in minutes ...)

---

If you are interested in learning about *[positional or spherical astronomy](https://www.britannica.com/science/positional-astronomy)*, then I advise you to visit [another Stack Exchange question about this topic](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/44368/best-books-on-spherical-astronomy). Personaly, I have had great fun with [Fundamental Astronomy](http://observatory.znu.ac.ir/files/uploaded/editor_files/observatory/files/Fundamental%2BAstronomy%2B5th%2BEdition.pdf). But in general, the formula is derived using the [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines).

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked at the link [1] you shared (which is great), but I don't seem to see how that was derived. Would you be able to link me to where I could learn more about htat?

Comment: Included in the answer. [Fundamental Astronomy](http://observatory.znu.ac.ir/files/uploaded/editor_files/observatory/files/Fundamental%2BAstronomy%2B5th%2BEdition.pdf) has the derivation. You can read more about it in my answer [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44376/25994).